# Setting up default proxy settings for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, proxy

I've inherited a completely undocumented application after starting a new job - the application is hosted in an environment I don't control and the people who DO have managed to break it. I have discovered this much:

The following setting in the web config causes *parts* of the application to break;

```
<defaultProxy enabled="false" />
```

a bug which is solved by setting the same value to "true", but that in turn breaks other parts. I discovered a "bypasslist" setting that can also be applied here and I'm pretty sure that's what I need to use, but I can't get the regular expression working correctly. I basically need to achieve the following;

- The setting above should be false, EXCEPT any requests to mydomain.host.com

I have tried this;

```
<defaultProxy enabled="false">
    <bypasslist>
        <add address = "mydomain.host.com" />
    </bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
```

and it's not working. I have a feeling that I need to do it the other way around, but as this application is undocumented this could be a wild goose chase that goes on for hours. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a logic which does exactly opposite of what bypasslist suppose to do when defaultProxy enabled.
You can implement your own proxy and modify the logic.
MSDN link(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w93fssz(v=vs.100))